# How do I create a scaleable GridLayout in QML?

Tags: frontend, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qqmlcomponent

I am currently trying to create an application that includes a Periodic table. I want to to display this as a GridLayout where each Element is represented as a GroupBox inside the Layout. The problem I am facing is that the GridLayout wont scale properly with the window that it is positioned in. It opens up as follows:

[GridLayout on first start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHqAs.png)

I can also scale up the window like this:

[GridLayout after upsizing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2h7o.png)

or donwscale it like the following:

[GridLayout after downsizing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ls39.png)

As you can see, the GridLayout doesnt seem to scale with the window size. Instead it seems to have a fixed size (Some elements are cut off from the beginning, if I scale down the window the elements are also being cut off)

Here is my code:

```js
Item {
    id: root
    Button {
        id: button
        checkable: true
        text: qsTr("Show")

        onClicked: window.show()
    }
    Window {
        id: window
        Material.accent: parent.Material.accent
        Material.background: parent.Material.background
        Material.foreground: parent.Material.foreground
        Material.primary: parent.Material.primary
        Material.theme: parent.Material.theme
        color: Material.background
        height: parent.height
        title: qsTr("Periodic table")
        width: parent.width

        GridLayout {
            id: grid
            columns: 18

            PeriodicTableElement {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                atomicWeight: qsTr("1.00794")
                electronConfiguration: qsTr("1s")
                elementName: qsTr("Hydrogen")
                elementSign: qsTr("H")
                ionizationEnergy: qsTr("13 5984")
                ordinalNumber: qsTr("1")
                unknownNumber: qsTr("S1/2")
            }
            Repeater {
                model: 16

                GroupBox {
                    background: Item {
                    }
                }
            }
            Repeater {
                model: 3

                PeriodicTableElement {
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    atomicWeight: qsTr("1.00794")
                    electronConfiguration: qsTr("1s")
                    elementName: qsTr("Hydrogen")
                    elementSign: qsTr("H")
                    ionizationEnergy: qsTr("13 5984")
                    ordinalNumber: qsTr("1")
                    unknownNumber: qsTr("S1/2")
                }
            }
            Repeater {
                model: 10

                GroupBox {
                    background: Item {
                    }
                }
            }
            Repeater {
                model: 6

                PeriodicTableElement {
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    atomicWeight: qsTr("1.00794")
                    electronConfiguration: qsTr("1s")
                    elementName: qsTr("Hydrogen")
                    elementSign: qsTr("H")
                    ionizationEnergy: qsTr("13 5984")
                    ordinalNumber: qsTr("1")
                    unknownNumber: qsTr("S1/2")
                }
            }
            Repeater {
                model: 100

                PeriodicTableElement {
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    atomicWeight: qsTr("1.00794")
                    electronConfiguration: qsTr("1s")
                    elementName: qsTr("Hydrogen")
                    elementSign: qsTr("H")
                    ionizationEnergy: qsTr("13 5984")
                    ordinalNumber: qsTr("1")
                    unknownNumber: qsTr("S1/2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried using anchors.fill: window for the GridLayout but it didnt seem to have any effect.

So do I make this GridLayout scale with the window item which is his parent?

Thanks in advance for any helpful comment.

Comment: Your `GridLayout` has no size, I mean you set no size for that. If you want it to fit the parent window you can use `anchors.fill: parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered `GridView` instead? This will have the following advantages:

- Provide the dimension of each delegate via `cellWidth` and `cellHeight`
- Provide a `ListModel` that helps us render the periodic table

Here's a mock implementation of the first two lines of the periodic table using this approach:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: parent.width / 18
        cellHeight: cellWidth * 2
        model: ElementsModel { }
        delegate: ElementDelegate { }
    }
}

// ElementsModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    id: elems
    ListElement { at: 1; sy: "H"; na: "Hydrogen"; co: "#ccf" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 2; sy: "He"; na: "Helium"; co: "pink" }
    ListElement { at: 3; sy: "Li"; na: "Lithum"; co: "#cff" }
    ListElement { at: 4; sy: "Be"; na: "Beryllium"; co: "#fcc" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 0; sy: ""; na: ""; co: "" }
    ListElement { at: 5; sy: "B"; na: "Boron"; co: "#ffe" }
    ListElement { at: 6; sy: "C"; na: "Carbon"; co: "#ccf" }
    ListElement { at: 7; sy: "N"; na: "Nitrogen"; co: "#ccf" }
    ListElement { at: 8; sy: "O"; na: "Oxygen"; co: "#ccf" }
    ListElement { at: 9; sy: "F"; na: "Flourine"; co: "#ccf" }
    ListElement { at: 10; sy: "Ne"; na: "Neon"; co: "pink" }
}

// ElementDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    property int cellWidth: GridView.view.cellWidth
    property int cellHeight: GridView.view.cellHeight
    width: cellWidth
    height: cellHeight
    color: co ? co : "#eee"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: sy
        font.pixelSize: cellHeight / 4
    }
    Text {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: na
        font.pixelSize: tm.scaledPixelSize
    }
    Text {
        text: at
        visible: at
        font.pixelSize: cellWidth / 5
    }
    TextMetrics {
        id: tm
        text: na
        font.pixelSize: 10
        property real scaledPixelSize: cellWidth / tm.width * font.pixelSize * 0.9
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)